# SQLAlchemy how do I query database for logged in user in flask?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SQLite database with a table in my models.py that shortened looks like this

```
# models.py
class Buyers(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'buyers'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    usertype = db.Column(db.String(64))
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, nullable=False)
```

In my views.py, I have function that looks like this

```
# view.py
@buyers_blueprint.route('/welcome')
@login_required
def welcome_user():
    user = Buyers.query.filter_by(firstname).first()
    return render_template('welcome.html', user=user)
```

I am trying to query the database in my view.py so I can send the `firstname` to an html page and dynamically update that users page.  I have importer the `models.py` into my `views.py`

How can I get the logged in user's name in a query so I can render it to my html?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I figured it out.  If I import `current_user` from `Flask_login`, then I have access.  So, I can use:

```
# view.py
@buyers_blueprint.route('/welcome')
@login_required
def welcome_user():
    user = current_user
    return render_template('welcome.html', user=user)
```

So, now I can just figure out how to give me first name only.